# Why are both my if statements activating?

Tags: javascript

I'm completely in awe right now, I usually am able to figure this stuff out quickly but this just isn't making any sense to me.

```js
 setTimeout(
 function(){
  
if (user1.length || pass1.length <= 6) {
 document.getElementById('verified').innerHTML="Error: Username or password too short!";
 alert('Running');
 setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1000);
}

if (user1.length && pass1.length >= 7) {
 document.getElementById('verified').innerHTML="You've been verified!";
}

 }
 ,2000);
```

For some reason even if they don't meet the rules, the first if statement is activated and the page reloads/alert pops up.

Comment: if `user1.length` is something and `pass1.length` is 7 or longer both will be true.

Comment: You need `user1.length <= 6 || pass1.length <= 6` presumably. It is not like English where you can say "if the username or password length is less than or equal to 6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your If statements are wrong. I think what you are looking for is:

```
if (user1.length <= 6 || pass1.length <= 6)
```

and

```
if (user1.length >= 7 && pass1.length >= 7)
```

When you use If in javascript anything holding a value returns true.
So if you write:

```
if (user1.length)
```

it will allways return true. You need to remember <= 6 on both sides of ||

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes it did. You explained it the best. So this is happening because user1.length will be true and execute. It's like saying if true=true and x<7 because of the format? This is good to know. Thanks :)

Comment: "When you use If in javascript anything holding a value returns true." — Unless that value is, for example, `0`, `""`, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, …

Comment: Thats "true" :P Just tried to make it simple :) The code needed small change to work and what the reason was :)

Answer (score 0):

user1.length looks suspicious to me.  Are you sure it's Boolean?  There is no operator or operand before the ||.

Answer (score 0):

It's because this condition

```
user1.length || pass1.length <= 6
```

If `user1.length` is non-zero then the second part will not even be checked because of [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Did you mean to use logical and `&&`?

Answer (score 0):

If user1.length is nonzero, that is a sufficient condition alone for the 1st if statement to be executed.

If additionally pass1.length >= 7, then also the 2nd statement will be executed.

Seemingly simple logic statements can be tricky, but it pays to stay cool and thing through them.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now why this wasn't working. I now have

```js
if (user1.length <= 6 || pass1.length <= 6) {
 document.getElementById('verified').innerHTML="Error: Username or password too short!";
 setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1000);
}

if (user1.length >= 7 && pass1.length >= 7) {
 document.getElementById('verified').innerHTML="You've been verified!";
}
```

which is working fine. Thanks :)